# Pandas - invalid entry in choicelist

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to filter on a column, and if the column contains a certain string, I'll append a specific value into a new column. Example:

```
conditions = [df['columnA'].str.contains('valueA')]
choices    = ['valueB']

df['columnB'] = np.select(conditions,  choices, default = 'default')
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid entry in choicelist: should be boolean ndarray
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But for me it working nice, in pandas `0.20.3`

Comment: Pandas version is 0.20.1, numpy is 1.12.1

Comment: The OP may have NaN values in `conditions`. For example, `df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':['valueA','valueB',np.nan]})` reproduces the problem.

Comment: @unutbu That was exactly the case. After trying to filter out NaN values, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parameter `na=False` in [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) because `NaN`s in `boolean mask` as commented [`unutbu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264672/pandas-invalid-entry-in-choicelist/47264884#comment81480308_47264672):

```
conditions = [df['columnA'].str.contains('valueA', na=False)]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':['valueA  ff','ss valueA','valueA 4','w','e',np.nan]})
print (df)
      columnA
0  valueA  ff
1   ss valueA
2    valueA 4
3           w
4           e
5         NaN
```

---

```
print (df['columnA'].str.contains('valueA'))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5      NaN
Name: columnA, dtype: object

print (df['columnA'].str.contains('valueA', na=False))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: columnA, dtype: bool
```

All together:

```
conditions = [df['columnA'].str.contains('valueA', na=False)]
choices    = ['valueB']

df['columnB'] = np.select(conditions,  choices, default = 'default')
print (df)
      columnA  columnB
0  valueA  ff   valueB
1   ss valueA   valueB
2    valueA 4   valueB
3           w  default
4           e  default
5         NaN  default
```